# Laravel - What is the usage of schedule time setting when lastly it uses OS cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, schedule

Laravel docs:

> - - - - - cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
>
> This Cron will call the Laravel command scheduler every minute. When
>   the schedule:run command is executed, Laravel will evaluate your
>   scheduled tasks and runs the tasks that are due.

I run these codes below in `app\Console\Kernel.php`:

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\done)->everyMinute();
$schedule->command('done:done')->everyMinute();
```

but none of them worked! so I run the command `php artisan schedule:run` but it runs only once and each time I want to make it trigger the job/command I should run that command so I tried to use the command above in Laravel docs. However again it didn't work every minute. So I tried to create a task in `Task Scheduler` and run it every 5 minutes(because it didn't have less than 5) now it's working but the usage of `->everyMinute()` is redundant because the schedule of Laravel only runs but the main job that is done is by Windows Task Scheduler. So how can I fix it in order not to use cron job nor windows task scheduler?

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to set every minutes on Windows Task Scheduler : https://somoit.net/windows/scheduled-task-every-minute

Comment: That's not the issue, it is OK if that runs every 5 minutes, but the problem is that why we should use Laravel schedule when all the actions can be done with cron job or windows scheduler? why Laravel schedule doesn't run every minute itself or at least to let its task to cron job? it just runs the command which is inside schedule which could be done with anything else in Laravel?

Comment: To my understanding, it's mostly to make the whole automation easier. Let's imagine you need a task executed every 15th of the month, it will be hard with only the cron. Maybe you will be able with Windows Task Scheduler. But you will need to configure on every platform you deploy the website. It's easier to set one cron every minute and let Laravel do the rest

Comment: But you could also use `php artisan done:done` in your Windows Task Schedule and not use the Kernel at all.

Comment: As I said the problem is that schedule not running every minute. It just runs each time I run command `php artisan schedule:run`.

Comment: Laravel know that a cron can't be executed more than every minute. So it doesn't keep a trace for job set to `everyMinute()` At the end, every time you run the command `php artisan schedule:run` it will run the job.

Comment: Now how can I make it to trigger the job every minute in Laravel?

Comment: `$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\done)->everyMinute();` and run a Windows Task Scheduler with `php artisan schedule:run` every minute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183873/discussion-between-kodfire-and-cbaconnier).

Comment: God bless @cbaconnier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so you can close the question.

As I said in the comments / chat

- You should be able to set every minutes on Windows Task Scheduler:
  http://somoit.net/windows/scheduled-task-every-minute
- You can also use `php artisan done:done` in your Windows Task Schedule and not use the Laravel Kernel at all.
- For the fact that `everyMinute()` is ignored when you run the job manually is because Laravel know that a cron can't be executed more than once a minute. So it doesn't keep a trace for a job set to `everyMinute()`. This mean, every time you run the command `php artisan schedule:run` it will run the job.

And has @kyslik mentioned in the chat : The scheduler is well covered in the official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling#introduction